firebase.firestore().colllection().where(_,_,*) 'value' argument expected
see i am creating an app using react-native wherein i have page where when i have added items to cart and when i click on place order it is showing above mentioned error.What i want is when user places his/her order(There is order collection in user collection which has feilds such as productId and quantity) the quantity which is being ordered should be subtracted from sub-product collection (there is id collection and availavble quantity named as quantity).
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";
import { useCart } from "../../config/CartContext";
import QuantityControlButton from "../../components/QuantityControlButton";
import FullWidthButton from "../../components/horizontalButton";
import firestore from "@react-native-firebase/firestore"; // Importing firestore
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { useUser } from "../../config/userContext";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

const Cart = () => {
  const { user } = useUser();
  const { cart, addToCart, subToCart, removeFromCart, clearCart } = useCart();
  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const reloadScreen = () => {
    setRefresh((prevRefresh) => !prevRefresh);
  };

  const isQuantityExceeded = (product) => {
    const cartItem = cart.find((item) => item.product.id === product.id);
    return cartItem && cartItem.quantity >= product.quantity;
  };

  const calculateTotalCost = () => {
    return cart.reduce(
      (total, item) => total + item.quantity * item.product.actualCost,
      0
    );
  };

  const handleDeleteItem = (productId) => {
    removeFromCart(productId);
  };

  const placeOrder = async () => {
    try {
      if (cart.length === 0) {
        Alert.alert(
          "Cart is Empty",
          "Please add items to your cart before placing an order."
        );
        return;
      }

      // Array to store the updates for each sub-product
      const updates = [];

      // Iterate over each item in the cart
      for (const item of cart) {
        const { productId, quantity } = item;

        // Query the sub-product based on the productId
        const querySnapshot = await firestore()
          .collection("sub-product")
          .where("id", "==", productId) // Using where from firestore import
          .get();

        // Update the quantity of the sub-product in Firestore
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const subProductRef = firestore()
            .collection("sub-product")
            .doc(doc.id);
          const newQuantity = doc.data().quantity - quantity;
          updates.push(subProductRef.update({ quantity: newQuantity }));
        });
      }

      // Update the user's orders array
      const ordersData = cart.map((item) => ({
        productId: item.product.id,
        quantity: item.quantity,
      }));

      await firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .update({
          orders: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...ordersData),
        });

      // Execute all updates in parallel
      await Promise.all(updates);

      // Clear the cart
      await clearCart();

      Alert.alert("Order Placed", "Your order has been sent for review.", [
        { text: "OK", onPress: reloadScreen },
      ]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error placing order:", error);
      Alert.alert("Error", "Failed to place order. Please try again later.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.header}>Your Cart</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={cart}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={styles.cartItem}>
            <Text style={{ color: "black" }}>{item.product.productName}</Text>
            <View style={styles.quantityControl}>
              <QuantityControlButton
                onPress={() => subToCart(item.product)}
                disabled={item.quantity === 1}
              >
                -
              </QuantityControlButton>
              <Text style={{ color: "black", marginHorizontal: 8 }}>
                {item.quantity}
              </Text>
              <QuantityControlButton
                onPress={() => addToCart(item.product)}
                disabled={isQuantityExceeded(item.product)}
              >
                +
              </QuantityControlButton>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleDeleteItem(item.product.id)}>
              <Text style={styles.deleteButton}>Remove</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={{ color: "black" }}>
              Price: {item.product.actualCost}
            </Text>
          </View>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) =>
          item.product && item.product.id ? item.product.id.toString() : ""
        }
      />
      <Text style={styles.totalCost}>
        Total Cost: INR {calculateTotalCost().toFixed(2)}
      </Text>
      <FullWidthButton title="Place Order" onPress={placeOrder} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom: 16,
    color: "black",
  },
  cartItem: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: "#ccc",
    paddingBottom: 8,
    marginBottom: 8,
  },
  quantityControl: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  deleteButton: {
    color: "red",
    marginTop: 8,
  },
  totalCost: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginTop: 16,
    color: "black",
  },
});

export default Cart;


[enter error generated when place order button clicked
